# When I try to store video to screenshot by using python opencv. It doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,480))

while(1):
 ret,frame = capture.read()

 cv2.imshow('webcam',frame)
 output.write(frame)

 if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

capture.release()
output.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I use this code but the error sign appeared.

it said

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python27/8.09_kk.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VideoWriter_fourcc'

but I can't understand this one how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using older version of OpenCV(version 2.4). Try `fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')`instead of `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`. It will work.

Comment: Thank you. It seems work. But actually it's not. It starts but in a second, it's gone....

Comment: What do you mean it's gone?. Does it throw an error?

Comment: no!! NO error but it doesn't work properly so I just changed to another version. Then it worked !! Thx a lot